# Yii2 in AuthClient google get user attributes. "Undefined index: email"

Tags: php, yii2, google-signin

i'm working in authentication with google in Yii2 Framework and i need help to get attributes because i'am unable to get the user attributes.

My web.php:

```
'google' => [
  'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Google',
             'authUrl' => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?display=popup',
             'clientId' => 'xxxxx',
             'clientSecret' => 'xxxxx',
],
```

My actions in Controller:

```
'auth' => [
   'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
   'successCallback' => [$this, 'successCallback'],
   'successUrl' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['selecionar-empresa']),
],
```

My successCallback:

```
$attributes = $client->getUserAttributes();
$user = User::find()->where(['email'=>$attributes['email']])->one();
```

But in successCallback return this error:

```
Undefined index: email
```

Could any one help me to achieve this, plis. tyyyy.

Comment: Check your *$attributes* `var_dump($attributes)`. It's may be **emails**

Comment: var_dump in my $attributes return empty, but count($attributes) return 14, :/

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$attributes = $client->getUserAttributes();
$user = User::find()->where(['email'=>$attributes['email']])->one();
```

With this and try.

```
$attributes = $client->getUserAttributes();
$user_email = $attributes['emails'][0]['value'];
$user = User::find()->where(['email'=>user_email])->one();
```

I hope it would work for you...